# redirect and pass data from jquery app to angular2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

What I am trying to achieve is, I am calling a nodejs login api endpoint from a jquery app by using ajax call. On successful login I want to redirect to a page in angular2 app. Also I want to pass some data to angular page. I tried that using localstorage and cookies but it gets reset on domain url change. any help is appreciated.

Comment: to pass data you can make use of router eg 

this.router.navigate(['/component2'], { queryParams: { page: pageNum } });

Comment: how about pass data through querystring? like "someurl?data=veryimportantdata"